# Vim: Getting gq Not to Displace `**' in Comment Block

Tags: c++, c, vim, formatting

Suppose I have a nice comment block, such as the one below

```
/*
** This is a nice comment block. Displace the `**'s and I will eat your nose! Also, here is a long line of text clearly longer than the textwidth, which should force gq to rearrange the lines. Wheeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee...
**
**
*/
```

and that I apply `gq` to format it and ensure that no line exceeds the character count. How can I get `gq` not to displace the initial `**'s that prepend each comment line?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `:help format-comments`. I get the result you want from

```
:set comments=s0:/*,mb:**,ex:*/
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response--your answer was really helpful. I just wanted to add that a safer and more complete change would be to add `exe "au FileType cpp set comments+='s0:/*,mb:**,ex:*/'"` to your .vimrc. If you want automatic comment leaders to be inserted when you hit return or use `o`, you should also add `set formatoptions+=or2`.

Comment: My bad, remove the single quotes in `comments+='s0:/*,mb:**,ex:*/'`.

Comment: Yeah, I usually have `formatoptions=tcqor`, but I decided to keep the answer simple. Seems like you're perfectly capable of setting everything how you like it :-)

Comment: Actually, I only learned about the `formatoptions` specifiers after your suggestion to use `:help format-comments`. I scrolled down a little, and read the section about `formatoptions`. I'm still sort of new to Vim, but I'm learning =)